# How to enforce a check on 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering what would be the best way to enforce a check on the ItemId of table 2. The point of the check would be to enforce that the row in table 3, where table 2 is linked to has the same ItemId just like in the example.

Edit: After ruud's comment I realized I might need to add a bit more detail since the current state is a bit too general.

Table2 is a link table in which Table4 and ItemTable come together, this table is also linked to Table3 but this is nullable. The PK in Table2 is a combination of T4ID and ItemId.

Relationships:

ItemTable to Table2 is one(ItemTable) to many(Table2).

ItemTable to Table3 is one(ItemTable) to many (Table3).

Table2 to Table3 is one(Table3) to many(Table2).

Table2 to Table4 is one(Table4) to many(Table2)

```
ItemTable          Table2                         Table3              Table4
ItemId(PK)         T4ID(PK FK)                    T3ID(PK)            T4ID(PK)
                   ItemId(PK FK) <- should match ->  ItemId(FK)
                   T3ID(FK)
```

Comment: While it is excellent question,will you explain little more ? what is the relation between ItemTable  and Table2   ,one to one  or one to many? Similarly what is the relation between table2 and table3 ?

Comment: Consider normalizing your database and eliminating `Table2.ItemId`; it is redundant since the same value is supposed to be in Table3. Assuming you indexed every PK and every FK in your database, joining the tables should be efficient; you can retrieve the ItemId from Table3.

Comment: @RuudHelderman - but it's sometimes necessary/desirable if one needs to e.g. have a check constraint in `Table2` that depends on the value of `ItemID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enforce this by declaring a "superkey" on `Table3` that includes both columns `T3ID` and `ItemID` (usually, this would be a Unique Key Constraint/Index).

You would then also declare an additional<sup>1</sup> FK between tables 2 and 3 on *both* `T3ID` and `ItemID`.

I.e. leave all existing constraints as they are. Then run:

```
ALTER TABLE Table3 ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Table3_Items UNIQUE (T3ID, ItemId);
ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Table2_ItemXRef
   FOREIGN KEY (T3ID, ItemId) references Table3 (T3ID, ItemID);
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically this then makes the plain FK based on `T3ID` redundant, but I usually prefer to leave it present to represent the "real" Foreign Key.

Comment: I edited my post to provide a bit more information about this, would your solution still count in this scenario?

Comment: Great ! I think itemtable and table4 are populated first in cycle,then table3 is populated from itemtable.then table2 is populated from both table3 and table4.Is this correct cycle ?

Comment: ok if T3ID+itemid in table3 is define as composite PK where T3ID may be identity int then this Composite PK can be reference as FK in table2,hence the problem solved.  Please answer both my question .

Comment: Almost table2 is populated from item and table4, table3 is optional(nullable) the remainder is correct.

Comment: As I indicate in my answer, we don't need to change the PK in table 3 - we just declare a superkey that includes the current PK and the `ItemID` column as an additional column, and use that in the additional/replacement FK from table 2.

Comment: So if I understand correctly in `Table3` we make ItemId and T3ID a joined PK. And after that I also link ItemId from `Table2` as a foreign key to `table3`'s ItemId

Comment: I've edited in the exact SQL I'd run in this scenario. We still (presumably) want `T3ID`, alone, to be the PK of `Table3`.

Comment: Added it to my tables and it works as intended, thanks for the help.